# Substituting a method return using NSubstitute, AutoFixture and AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute

Tags: c#, autofixture, nsubstitute

I am attempting to use NSubstitute (1.8.2), AutoFixture (3.33) and AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute (3.33) as follows:

I have a poco which has a method and is used in my application. In order to test my application I need to mock the poco and what it returns from the method.

This is the poco (simplified from our actual model)

```
public class SamplePoco
{
    public string SampleString { get; set; }

    public virtual string GetFormattedString()
    {
        return this.SampleString + " formatted";
    }
}
```

and this test

```
[TestMethod]
public void SampleTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization());

    var substitute = fixture.Create<SamplePoco>();

    var formattedString = fixture.Create<string>();

    substitute.GetFormattedString().Returns(formattedString);

    // ... test goes here
}
```

I have determined this using code samples I have found for AutoFixture.AutoMoq as I have not been able find any specific samples for AutoFixture.AutoNSubstitute.

However, this fails with the following error:

> NSubstitute.Exceptions.CouldNotSetReturnDueToNoLastCallException:
>   Could not find a call to return from.

What am I doing wrong?

Using NSubstitute works as expected:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SampleTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization());

    var substitute = Substitute.For<SamplePoco>();

    var formattedString = fixture.Create<string>();

    substitute.GetFormattedString().Returns(formattedString);

    // ... test goes here
}
```

However, I want to use AutoFixture as the actual poco has many more properties and methods and the methods are more complex than this simple example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you wrote, `SamplePoco` class is a `POCO`, so when you call `fixture.Create<SamplePoco>()` in first test, you are getting a fresh new instance of `SamplePoco` class created by `AutoFixture` using reflection and invoking default constructor.

I think your first test is fine, `AutoFixture` create also a `SampleString` so, you don't need to stub `GetFormattedString` method.

And from testing perspective your `GetFormattedString` method contains behavior so you should rather test it in that way:

```
public void SampleTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization());

   var poco = fixture.Create<SamplePoco>();
   Assert.AreEquals(string.Format("{0} {1}", poco.SampleString, "formatted"), poco.GetFormattedString());
}
```

`AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization` is used if `AutoFixture` is asked to create instance of abstraction (either interface or abstract class) and it also setup other members of that abstraction to return values from `AutoFixture`

But if you want explicitly tell `AutoFixture` to create `POCO` class using `NSubstitute` you can use `AutoDataAttribute` combined with `SubstituteAttribute`. More information about this you can find [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/pull/430)

---

**EDIT**

If you are using test framework that doesn't allow for using `AutoData` feature, you can create customization that changes `AutoFixture` behavior for `SamplePoco` class.

```
public class SamplePocoSubstituteCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Register(() => Substitute.For<SamplePoco>());
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SampleTest()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredNSubstituteCustomization())
                                   .Customize(new SamplePocoSubstituteCustomization());

    var substitute = fixture.Create<SamplePoco>();

    var formattedString = fixture.Create<string>();

    substitute.GetFormattedString().Returns(formattedString);

    // ... test goes here
}
```

Comment: I think you have slightly misunderstood. I am not trying to test `SamplePoco`. I am testing a different class which uses `SamplePoco` and don't want `SamplePoco.GetFormattedString` to be called therefore I want `SamplePoco.GetFormattedString` to return my mocked value when I test this other class.

Comment: But why you don't want to `SamplePoco.GetFormattedString` to not to be called? What is the reason to stub `SamplePoco.GetFormattedString`?

Comment: This is just a simple example. The actual `GetFormattedString` does more than this including further calls that I don't want to happen when I test my outer class.

Comment: So, the solution with using `AutoDataAttribute` and `SubstituteAttribute` doesn't seem good for you?. Also, please take a look at warning note about substituting classes [NSubstitute creating a substitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/)

Comment: I will take a look at the attributes link and report back, I was just quickly answering your comment. I am aware of the issue with classes :) that's how I knew to make the method `virtual`

Comment: I've had a look at that link but cannot figure out how to actually implement this. Have you an example?

Comment: It appears that it's all based on xUnit - we aren't using that

Comment: I edited answer and added example how to add customization that change `AutoFixture` to behave as you expected in first test

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!